# Fresh install PHP 7.1.1, php.ini is missing

Tags: solaris, php

I can't find where the php.ini file is on a fresh install of PHP 7.1.1 in Solaris.

```
find / -name "php.ini" ## < No result
./php --ini 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/app/php/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

ls -lrt /opt/app/php/lib
drwxr-xr-x  15 root     root          23 Feb  8 11:59 php

find / -name "php.ini" ## < no result
```

Answer (score 1):

found at http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

**step 6**      `cp php.ini-development /usr/local/lib/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Found it [php.ini on solaris](https://www.mail-archive.com/php-general@lists.php.net/msg75739.html)

> rename php.ini-dist that's with the php source code to php.ini and copy it
>   to /usr/local/lib

(from the location: /opt/app/php/lib/php.ini-dist)